# How to create copy of object that can be modified?

Tags: java, swing

I have a list of objects in a Swing GUI. The user can select one and edit the object before having to confirm the change by pressing a button. The state of the object is done with binding.

My problem is; the user should be able to cancel the editing, reverting the changes. The original data is already changed.

I guess I need to have a copy of the object, but I don't know what the correct way is to obtain one. Clone method, copy constructor, serialization,... They all seem to have drawbacks.

This must be a common requirement and I wonder which approach I should use? What is the most elegant way?

Comment: I would use a clone, it seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: Take a look at [Add an undo/redo function to your Java apps with Swing](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076698/core-java/add-an-undo-redo-function-to-your-java-apps-with-swing.html)

Comment: Would you say that it is better than copying?

Comment: just assign the your obj to your uncreated obj of same class in any class

Answer (score 2):

One can maintain a **history of undoable actions** so a list of Undos is possible. Doing an actionPerformed registers the reverse undo action restoring the state.

That would fit nicely.

---

- A bit dated, [und/redo](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076698/core-java/add-an-undo-redo-function-to-your-java-apps-with-swing.html) essay with patterns.
- [UndoManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html).

Comment: Could you provide some more implementation details?